# SQLite view and query on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two tables one to store a task and one to evaluate the task:

```
create table task(
  _id  integer primary key autoincrement,
  task text not null);

create table eval (
  _id    integer primary key autoincrement,
  taskid integer,
  eval   integer);
```

Some data:

```
INSERT INTO task VALUES (1,"A small job");
INSERT INTO task VALUES (2,"A easy job");
INSERT INTO eval VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO eval VALUES (2,1,2);
INSERT INTO eval VALUES (3,2,1);
INSERT INTO eval VALUES (4,2,2);
```

Then a view joining the two tables:

```
  CREATE VIEW status AS 
  SELECT eval._id   AS _id, 
  eval.taskid   AS taskid, 
  eval.eval     AS eval, 
  task.task 
  FROM task JOIN eval 
  ON task._id = eval.taskid;
```

SQLite Database Browser doesn't support views. What's a good database browser for android development on linux?

Secondly, consider this query: Select the highest evaluation on each task

```
SELECT s.task, s.eval 
FROM status AS s 
JOIN (
  SELECT task, MAX(eval) AS maxeval 
  FROM status 
  GROUP BY task
) AS pm ON s.task = pm.task AND s.eval = pm.maxeval;
```

Resulting in:

```
s.task       s.eval
A easy job   2
A small job  2
```

How do I implement this query in an Android app? I've tried to pack it into a `Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query` method and its siblings without much luck.

Is there a way to just pass the SQL query as a string into the database and get a result set back?

Comment: SQLiteDatabase.execSql(String);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you can use [SQLiteManager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) a firefox add-onn. It is a visual
  browser for sqlite database. I am using it and it is very nice.
- If you want to learn sqlite syntax, you can use this [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/databases/sqlitetutorial/).
- You can use `db.execSQL(sqlCommand)` fore update, write and delete
  operations. For read operations you can use `cursor =
  db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);`, where db is `SQLiteDatabase`'s object.

Comment: Thanks, I´ll check out the SQLiteManager

Comment: And the winner is...... https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/ This is a much better tool than SQLite Database Browser. Thanks Muhammad!

Comment: If Firefox says it can't install it because Firefox has updated, and the plugin's not ready for the latest rev, you can possibly install it directly from google code repo [here](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/downloads/list). Worked for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1) SQLite Browser - http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

2) Use SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs) where sql is a string with a query

Comment: +1 for rawQuery(), I assume SQLite browser is also good.  I just use the sqlite3 program from the Android SDK.

Comment: But I still need a good database browser that support views - anyone?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with: database browser that support views? SQLite Browser has a GUI, so you can see what's in the database, and run queries...

Comment: Try to run the scripts above in SQLite Database Browser: You can query the view, so it`s there, but it`s only the tables that is visible in the GUI. As far as I can see; there is no way to inspect the view.

Comment: And the winner is...... [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) This is a much better tool than SQLite Database Browser. Thanks Muhammad!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try .execSQL . You can use it like

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE User (username varchar(5) , pwd varchar(15))");

Comment: Yes, you can´t return anything:`Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.
It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(String, String, ContentValues), update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]), et al, when possible.` From JavaDoc.